# Access Passthrough DSN-less Oracle Query

Tags: oracle, ms-access, vba, odbc

I've got something in Excel that returns my table from an Oracle Database without DSN:

```vb
With ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:= _
  "ODBC;DRIVER={Microsoft ODBC for Oracle};CONNECTSTRING=(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=" & IP1 & ")(PORT=XXXX))" & _
  "(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=" & SvcNm & ")));" & _
  "UID=" & UserName & ";" & _
        "PWD=" & PassWord & " & ";", Destination:=Range("A1"))
  .Sql = strSQL
  .FieldNames = False
  .RefreshStyle = xlOverwriteCells
  .RowNumbers = False
  .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
  .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
  .HasAutoFormat = False
  .BackgroundQuery = False
  .TablesOnlyFromHTML = True
  .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=True
  .SavePassword = False
  .SaveData = True
  .Delete
End With
```

This works to get me what i'm after. But if I wanted a similar approach in Access, I tried this:

```vb
    Dim db As DAO.Database
    Dim qdf As DAO.QueryDef
    Dim rs As DAO.Recordset

    Set db = CurrentDb
    Set qdf = db.CreateQueryDef("")
    qdf.Connect = "ODBC;DRIVER={Microsoft ODBC for Oracle};CONNECTSTRING=(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=" & IP & ")(PORT=XXXX))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=" & svcname & ")));" & _
    "Uid=" & Username & ";PWD=" & password &";"


    qdf.Sql = "---some query"

    qdf.ReturnsRecords = True

    Set rs = qdf.OpenRecordset
```

I end up with an error here of:

[image: The error]

Is there anything I can here or is there no equivalent for querytables in Access?

Comment: Are you absolutely sure the connection strings and SQL between Excel and Access are exactly the same? Do a `Debug.Print` of both and paste them in text editor for comparison.

Comment: Identical. I'm copying and pasting from one to another. I also verified the connectionstring from http://connectionstrings.com/oracle to make sure I was using it correctly. This is the error I get using the correct connectionstring, anything else results in an ODBC error.

Comment: As for equivalent of QueryTables, remove the recordset call and simply open query, `DoCmd.Open "mySavedQuery"`, after releasing qdf, `Set qdf = Nothing`, to save changes. This will open an Excel like table or rather Excel opens an Access like table!

Comment: Exact same error doing that. Opening up the saved query under Access on the side panels also reflects the same error... Not sure why.

Comment: As far as I can see, the connection strings aren't exact copies given your current code (e.g. `Uid` vs `UID`). My usual advice is to create a file DSN, and adapt that into a connection string.

Comment: Yeah, I edited the strings to match resulting in the same error>

Comment: Just for access.

Comment: I do not want to be a nuisance. Forgive me but once again, did you `Debug.Print` the connection string **and** SQL statement in the Immediate Window of VBA (Ctrl + G) in **both** Excel and Access? My other theory is Excel and Access is not running on same user and machine. Is this correct? Place `Debug.Print <string>` in your code before error and output will render in Immediate Window at bottom.

Comment: Sorry about the late reply Parfait, here you go (they are also running on the same machine)



Access -`ODBC;DRIVER={Microsoft ODBC for Oracle};CONNECTSTRING=(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=******)(PORT=****))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=BAIM)));UID=****;PWD=****;`




Excel - `ODBC;DRIVER={Microsoft ODBC for Oracle};CONNECTSTRING=(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=******)(PORT=****))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=BAIM)));UID=****;PWD=****;`

Comment: Is your Access 64 bit while your Excel is 32 bit?

Comment: ODBC driver `Microsoft ODBC for Oracle` is [deprecated](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/odbc/microsoft/odbc-driver-for-oracle) for ages, you should not use it. Download and install the driver from Oracle: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/dotnet/downloads/net-downloads-160392.html I think `DAO` is also a bit "old-style", have a look at ADODB (ActiveX Data Objects)

Comment: Unfortunately, i'm limited in what I can use... The systems i'm dealing with can't change unfortunately. And i'm unable to install anything on top of what the system already has. These are 32bit versions of both.

Comment: And your SQL statement? Edit your post and add these items (SQL and connection strings comparison). See edit link at bottom. Then delete your long comment as will I.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you create a pass-through query, and get it working. You can create + run a PT query without any code. Get the PT query working 100% with the Access UI, and THEN attempt code.

So create the PT query. When you click on that PT query in the Access UI does it work?

Once (and ONLY AFTER) you get this query working, then you can run that PT query in code like this:

```
Dim rst As DAO.Recordset
Set rst = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("qryPassR")
```

If you need to modify the raw SQL of the oracle query, then you can go:

```
Dim rst As DAO.Recordset

With CurrentDb.QueryDefs("qryPassR")
   .SQL = "select * from tblHotels"
   Set rst = .OpenRecordset
End With
```

And if you want to execute a stored procedure, then go

```
With CurrentDb.QueryDefs("qryPassR")
   .SQL = "exec storedProc"
   .ReturnsRecords = False
   .Execute
End With
```

So once you create ONE working PT query, then you can use it over and over in code like above. So no need to place that connection string stuff in code – just create the PT query and it will save + manage the connection string for you.

Comment: I'm running into the same error when trying to execute through the PT without VBA at all. Using the same Connectionstring within the PT ODBC Conn Str input. Which according to connectionstring.com is correct. So i'm not sure why i'm getting the error.

Comment: I would create a new connection. Another way is to hit ctrl-g to jump to the debug window, and type in ? currentdb.TableDefs("linked table name").Connect     - in other words, take a existing and known and working connection from a linked table and use that. So no use to try VBA code until such time that the simple PT query works 100% from the Access UI. Your connection simply not working. Do you have a working linked table? (as noted grab the connection info from that).

Comment: So at the end of the  day, you need to get a simple and basic connection working to your server. If no linked tables or any other connection does not work, then worrying about code is WAY too early in this process. You have to get simple linked tables working and you have to get a basic connection working. Don't try and solve VBA code at the same time as simply getting your connection working. Get a simple linked table working. I mean, if your connection never worked, and you don't have a working connection, then this issue has near zero to do with your original question and post.

Answer (score 0):

Try using Driver=Microsoft ODBC for Oracle; instead of Driver={Microsoft ODBC for Oracle}.  The later is ADO format.

Comment: DSN-less in DAO requires DSN=; parameter